# I can not catch errors

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Hi I have made ​​an if query and this question goes to the server. However, the server will only accept 2 numbers and a decimal number (99.9) but I have to count up to 100, the server always gives me an error.
Do you know maybe how I can catch this error so that my software anyway Counts to 100. It must not be output to the server. The program should run only on. He shall not make it stop at 99 again and continue counting down So when he comes at 99 and then 100.

public static void main(String[] args) 
     {

```
    boolean positive = true;
    int counter = 0;


    while (true) 
    {

        if (counter >= 99)
        {
            positive = false;
        }
        if (counter <=-99)
        {
            positive = true;
        }

        if (positive == true)
        {   
            counter ++;
        }
        else 
        {   
            counter --;     
        }
```

That's my "Software" And the Exception is:

```
Exception = Response was of unexpected text/html ContentType.  Incoming portion of HTML stream: <html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/7.0.47 - Error report</title><style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/dao/QueryTimeoutException</h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Exception report</p><p><b>message</b> <u>Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/dao/QueryTimeoutException</u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.</u></p><p><b>exception</b> <pre>org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/dao/QueryTimeoutException
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:948)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:186)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
</pre></p><p><b>root cause</b> <pre>java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/dao/QueryTimeoutException
    org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.&lt;init&gt;(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:86)
    org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.&lt;init&gt;(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:102)
    org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcAccessor.getExceptionTranslator(JdbcAccessor.java:99)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:605)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:849)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcInsert.executeInsertAndReturnKeyHolderInternal(AbstractJdbcInsert.java:436)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcInsert.executeInsertAndReturnKeyInternal(AbstractJdbcInsert.java:417)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcInsert.doExecuteAndReturnKey(AbstractJdbcInsert.java:371)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcInsert.executeAndReturnKey(SimpleJdbcInsert.java:122)
    de.fraunhofer.iao.sharedefleet.energiemanagement.backend.ChargePointLogDAO.insertChargePointRequest(ChargePointLogDAO.java:65)
    de.fraunhofer.iao.sharedefleet.energiemanagement.facade.PlugAndChargeFacade.handleHeartbeatRequest(PlugAndChargeFacade.java:55)
    de.fraunhofer.iao.sharedefleet.energiemanagement.facade.PlugAndChargeFacade.requestChargingState(PlugAndChargeFacade.java:142)
    de.fraunhofer.iao.sharedefleet.energiemanagement.services.EVSEHeartbeatEndpoint.requestChargingState(EVSEHeartbeatEndpoint.java:34)
    sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor143.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.MethodEndpoint.invoke(MethodEndpoint.java:134)
    org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter.invokeInternal(DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter.java:240)
    org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.AbstractMethodEndpointAdapter.invoke(AbstractMethodEndpointAdapter.java:53)
    org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.dispatch(MessageDispatcher.java:233)
    org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.receive(MessageDispatcher.java:173)
    org.springframework.ws.transport.support.WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.handleConnection(WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.java:88)
    org.springframework.ws.transport.http.WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.handle(WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.java:59)
    org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet.doService(MessageDispatcherServlet.java:239)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:186)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
</pre></p><p><b>root cause</b> <pre>java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.dao.QueryTimeoutException.
```

So I hope you can help me.

Thats my main

```
public class Main {





 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {

    boolean positive = true;
    int counter = 0;


    while (true) 
    {

        if (counter >= 99)
        {
            positive = false;
        }
        if (counter <=-99)
        {
            positive = true;
        }

        if (positive == true)
        {   
            counter ++;
        }
        else 
        {   
            counter --;     
        }









        CloudCommunicator ccc = new CloudCommunicator("sh1");
        EnergyManagerJob emj = ccc.SendRequest (true  , true, 1 , 100 , "Nori2");



        System.out.println("\nmax Current: "  + emj.allowedMaximumCurrent);
        System.out.println("charging status: " +emj.chargingPending);
        System.out.println("power: " +emj.powerOn);




        try 
        {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }   




    }   // end of while


 }// end of main
```

Comment: What is the relationship between your `main` method and the web application?

Comment: Where is the code that contacts the remote server?

Comment: add `spring-mvc` lib at least

Answer (score 0):

For the error you've posted, you'll need to [find and add the `spring-tx` library](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-tx) to your classpath. You can add it to `/WEB-INF/lib`.

However, I don't see how the exception you've posted and the code you've posted relate to each other.

Comment: My software sends data to a server. I work on a client, the server does not come from me. The one who makes the server has determined that you only can send a two-digit number nummer  and can pass a number after the decimal point. But what I want to do is trap the error so further makes my program even if the server reports an error 100. He should then make a text output that the number 100 is not accepted by the server, but he should still continue to return value counting. (100) 99 98 ....

Comment: @user3297407 I hope you understand that the error you are experiencing has absolutely nothing to do with the code you've shown us.

Comment: @user3297407 You cannot catch an exception thrown on a **sever** from a **client**.

Answer (score 0):

The server may be missing a dependency: `spring-tx`.

You can download the jar or add it to your project dependencies here: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-tx

Answer (score 0):

Sotirios Delimanolis is right, please also avoid putting **while(true)** because it is an infinite loop, you can put for example **while(positive)**, this will increment the counter until it gets to 99.